# Sharing Sitecore content and layout to native app (iOS and Android)

Tags: content-delivery

Have framework build in `Sitecore` for the website and would like to utilize same components, content and layout for native `iOS` and `Android` app.
I believe content sharing is possible. Can components and layout be share through `Sitecore` as well?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to shar the content among the different channel is `Sitecore layout service`. But for this you must have to use `Sitecore JSS/Headless`. You can check this here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/sitecore-layout-service.html

But if you are not using `Sitecore JSS/Headless`, you can share the content by JSON or device (mobile) given in the below screenshot. It would return data in JSON format.

[image]

You can add your layout and component presentation as per your requirement.

Hoping it will help you.

Thanks